# What is a line to neutral load?

Tags: electrical

I'm looking at the electrical code and it states "Multiwire branch circuits shall supply only line-to-neutral loads." Could someone explain what line-to-neutral loads are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A multi wire branch has a neutral and 2 lives in opposite phase.

[image]

What the code says is that you may only allow loads connected to only 1 live and neutral (V1 and V2 in the picture) and you are not allowed to have a live to live load (V1+V2) (which would have double voltage).

Answer (score 0):

This is also an unnecessary line in the code.

Here is the text:

> **(C) Line-to-Neutral Loads.**
>
> Multiwire branch circuits shall supply only line-to-neutral loads.
>
> Exception No. 1: A multiwire branch circuit that supplies only one
>   utilization equipment.
>
> Exception No. 2: Where all ungrounded conductors of the multiwire
>   branch circuit are opened simultaneously by the branch-circuit
>   overcurrent device.*

See exception 2? This says you can also supply line to line loads if "all ungrounded conductors of the multiwirebranch circuit are opened simultaneously".

Thing is, in 210.4(B) it already tells us:

> **(B) Disconnecting Means.**
>
> Each multiwire branch circuit shall be provided with a means that will
>   simultaneously disconnect all ungrounded conductors at the point where
>   the branch circuit originates.*

So basically **(C)** is an unneeded section.

Comment: While this answer is very informative, it doesn't address the question that is asked. Which was "*What is a line to neutral load?*".

Comment: OK?.......I couldn't add it as a comment and get the proper formatting I wanted.

Comment: 210.4(B) and 210.4(C) are subtly different, actually!  "Simultaneously disconnect" with regards to disconnecting means is the equivalent of two fuses in a two-pole pullout disconnect holder or two single pole breakers handle tied together i.e. both poles are manually turned off together but may trip/blow independently, while "where all ungrounded conductors of the MWBC are opened simultaneously by the branch-circuit overcurrent device" means that the overcurrent device must *trip* both poles in response to an overcurrent on only one -- i.e. it must be a common trip device

Answer (score 0):

Line to neutral loads are loads that require a path for electricity to come back to its source. An outlet circuit (120 v line to neutral) in your house for example is a line to neutral load. It carries the unbalance provided by the "hot" wire back to the panel so it can provide electricity continuously to whatever needs it. Your oven circuit (240 v line to line) would not be a line to neutral load, generally. It only consumes power to do its job. Although, ranges nowadays are more than likely to have electronics like a clock or timer function in which cases they would be both 120/240 circuits